# Notify Angular a variable has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just starting with Angular and have a quick question:

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Joe","account": "12355845454","rent": "500"}]');

angular.module('ngAppRentManager', []).
controller('RentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tenants = data;
}]);

setTimeout(function () {
    data = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Sara","account": "54874","rent": "600"}]');
    console.log("Poke Angular!");
}, 2000);
```

When my variable `data` has changed. How do I tell Angular to update the model?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/pjsx1460/2/)**

Comment: see $timeout service. This makes sure your angular is aware of your async operations .

Comment: or call $scope.apply() to ask angular to check data, and update bindings.

Comment: @Subin $scope is not defined in the current context, how do I reference it? I'm not doing anything async btw, I'm changing `data` when a user loads a csv file in a file input. Should I approach this differently?

Comment: check update up my answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pjsx1460/3/

Comment: make sure $scope is visible in current context. you can invoke async operation from within controller as shown in fiddle above. Also make sure you are setting modifying `$scope.tenants`, not variable `data`

Comment: Might want to fire `$scope.$apply();` onchange on your slider

Answer (score 3):

ad .apply() to your code like this

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Joe","account": "12355845454","rent": "500"}]');

angular.module('ngAppRentManager', []).
controller('RentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tenants = data;

  setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.tenants = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Sara","account": "54874","rent": "600"}]');
    console.log("Poke Angular!");
     $scope.$apply();
}, 2000);

}]);
```

http://jsbin.com/tirebavaho/1/

Comment: it does - check jsbin  example

Comment: Your changed your whole answer after I wrote my comment. Before it was `data = JSON.parse(...)` Next time you post please check your code before posting and not after...

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$timeout` service to stay within [angular context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Joe","account": "12355845454","rent": "500"}]');  

angular.module('ngAppRentManager', []).
controller('RentCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.tenants = data;
}]);

$timeout(function () {
    data = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Sara","account": "54874","rent": "600"}]');
    console.log("Poke Angular!");
}, 2000);
```

Comment: [Link to comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689447/notify-angular-a-variable-has-changed/26689794?#comment41998544_26689794)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working solution for my problem

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Joe","account": "12355845454","rent": "500"}]');

angular.module('ngAppRentManager', []).
controller('RentCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.tenants = data;
    $scope.getData = function (newData) {
        $scope.tenants = newData;
        $scope.$apply();
    };
}]);

setTimeout(function () {
    data = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Sara","account": "54874","rent": "600"}]');
    console.log("Poke Angular!");
    // Is this the best way to call Angular from outside scope?
    angular.element($('#control')).scope().getData(data);
}, 2000);
```

If this can be improved by calling the controller directly, please let me know.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/pjsx1460/6/)**

Comment: JimmyRare's answer is correct. no need to use #id's while working with angular.... neither DOM manipulation NOR getting handle to elements should be done with angular

Comment: I have no use for `timeout` in reality I want to update my view after a function outside the controller parsed a CSV file.

Comment: Do not use scope.apply inside angular context, that makes your method attached to the controller scope unusable from angular (as it is going to throw phase error). So ideally scope.apply must be invoked at the source not in the function that is effected. I.e you would do it in the setTimeout in your case. Also what does this timeout of 2sec give you? what if your process takes more time or even much less time you make the user wait?

Comment: @PSL the `setTimeout` is there for the sole purpose to simulate a user changing `data` at a certain point and has absolutely nothing to do with the actual code.

Comment: but how will you fetch the data, using $http??

Comment: @Jonathan Alright that is fine.. However i mentioned my point about scope.$apply it still applies in your case :). And also if you convert whatever service you are using to parse a csv file you could wrap it and make an angular service and you will not have to do all these, You may want to read up on services, run phase(if you want to do it during your app initialization and have the service manage the data though promise pattern) of the app etc..

Comment: @PSL I'm rewriting an existing application to learn Angular and get rid of all the code where I'm creating most of the DOM in custom JS. I already have the code that handles the data.

Comment: @harish I get it from a HTML file input where the user can drop a CSV which is then parsed for the relevant fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch("data", function (newVal, oldVal) {
     //your update code
     //newVal is your data's changed value
});
```