# Access $scope outside the controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to access a object in a function within my controller.

Here is my controller, in the controller i have a function called '**fetchAll**';

```
 app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $scope.fetchAll = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'xxx',
        data: testArray,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.testObj = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    })
}
```

}])

I want to access **$scope.testObj** in my index.html, since I want to display its content.

Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking at the angular basics. In your index.html use ng-controller directive to specify the controller and bind it to the view using the scope binding variable i.e testObj as is. [Official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) itself has good examples..

Comment: very basic angular, have a look at the tutorials first - egghead.io has awesome vids to get you started...

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491879/access-scope-from-html) answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this question myself, thanks to for the comments that helped me figure it out.

The confusing part for me was that I had my object in a function inside the controller, but it didn't matter at all.

```
<div ng-controller="testController"
   <ul>
      <li>{{testObj}}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689447/notify-angular-a-variable-has-changed) with setting data.

I've modified the solution for your case:

```
angular.module('ngAppRentManager', []).
controller('RentCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.tenants = data;
    $scope.setData = function (newData) {
        $scope.testObj  = newData;
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    // Means to get data.
    $scope.getData = function () {
        return  console.log($scope.testObj )
    };
}]);

setTimeout(function () {
    // Get the data.
    angular.element($('#control')).scope().getData(data);
}, 2000);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/pjsx1460/7/)**

Comment: I didnt downvote, but you are doing DOM manipulation controller, its not the way. its a wrong answer for future users.

Comment: Can you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26689794/2407212 so I know the right answer?